# Volume of Solids of Revolution

Tags: calculus

Why the volumes of solids of revolution about $x$ axis of two plane curves that have the same area are different?

Let's take for example $f(x)=1$ between $0$ and $1$ that has the same area as $g(x)=\cos(x)$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$ but the volume of the solids of the revolution about $x$ axis is different.

What am I missing?

Comment: The nature of the curves themselves.

Comment: A triangle and a squadre of the same perimeter are not bound to have the same area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytically, the reason is that the integral for the area enclosed between the plane curve and the $x$ axis over the interval $[a,b]$ is given by

$$A=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) \, dx$$

while the volume of the solid of revolution about the $x$ is given by

$$V=\int_{a}^{b} \pi f^2(x) \, dx$$

Consequently, the integrals for area and volume are different.

So when we have two curves $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ such that

$$A_1=A_2$$

there won't be any reason to conclude

$$V_1=V_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Those curves do not generate the same surface when rotated trough the "x" axis. The first one gives rise to a cylinder and the other one is clearly not, so the volumes are diferent.